# ZF2 populate form collections element with child objects

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

Based on the Zend Framework 2 manual ([here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html)) I made a form like this:

```
class ParentForm extends Form
{
    public function init()
    {   
        $this->setName('parent_form')
             ->setAttribute('method', 'post')
             ->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(true))
             ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Application\Form\Fieldset\Parent',
            'name' => 'parent',
            'options' => array(
                'label'                => 'Parent',
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'name' => 'csrf'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Send'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

And the 'parent' fieldset:

```
class ParentFieldset extends Fieldset
{    
    protected $count = 2;    

    public function init()
    {   
        $this->setName('parent_fieldset')
             ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
             ->setObject(new Model\Parent());

        $this->add(array('type' => 'Element\MyField'));            

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'collection',
            'name' => 'children',
            'options' => array(
                'label'                  => 'Children',
                'count'                  => $this->count,
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'allow_add'              => true,
                'target_element'         => array(
                    'type'    => 'Application\Form\Fieldset\Child',
                    'name'    => 'child',
                    'options' => array(
                        'label' => child',
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ));
    }

    public function setCount($count)
    {
        $this->count = max($count, 2);
    }
}
```

This works great to hydrate my Parent object with data obtained from my form. A var_dump of the resuting object will look like:

```
object(Parent)
public myField  => foo
public children =>
 array => 
  0 => object(Child)
    public field1 => value1
    public field2 => value2
    ....
  1 => object(Child)
    .....
  2 => object(Child)
    .....
```

But I cannot figure out how to populate this multi-dimensional form with the above object if hydrated from the database (for editing purposes). How can I do that?

Note: the count property in the form is set to the same number of children as in the object.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Yes, basically, if you set $form->count to the number children and then $form->bind($object) it works. When I find some time I will post a more elaborate answer.

Comment: Hi tihe. I found just using $form->bind($object) did the trick. I didn't need to adjust the count property.